# 'RestKit/RKSerialization.h' file not found via Cocapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, restkit, restkit-0.20

I've been trying for hours but couldn't find any solution that helped me to solve the issue.

my Podfile looks like:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

inhibit_all_warnings!

xcodeproj 'MyProject.xcodeproj'

# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '6.0'

target 'MyProject' do

pod 'ZBarSDK', '~> 1.3.1'
pod 'RestKit'

end
```

I have tried different options but none of them are working.

**`Header Search Paths`** and **`Library Search Paths`** & **`Framework Search Paths`** have: **`$(inherited)`** as value.

```
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h> // works fine
#import <RestKit/RKSerialization.h> // I get 'RestKit/RKSerialization.h' file not found
#import <RestKit/RKJSONParserJSONKit.h> // 'RestKit/RKJSONParserJSONKit.h' file not found
```

UPDATE:

```
cocapods version - 0.38.0
XCode version - Version 7.0 (7A220)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve it by using the following `Podfile` and recreated the project from scratch. I think the problem was that the XCode was created with older version and might interfere something.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

inhibit_all_warnings!

xcodeproj 'MyProject.xcodeproj'

# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '6.0'

target 'MyProject' do

pod 'ZBarSDK', '~> 1.3.1'
pod 'RestKit', '0.10.3' //This is the lastest version that has RKJSONParserJSONKit file, next version is not backward compatibility with previous version, you need to update the code
pod 'FileMD5Hash', :podspec => 'FileMD5Hash.podspec.json'
end
```

and `FileMD5Hash.podspec.json` content. You will need to create that file on root folder of the `Podfile`, [thanks &  +1 to @ryanmaxwell](https://github.com/JoeKun/FileMD5Hash/issues/7#issuecomment-98904188)

```
{
  "name": "FileMD5Hash",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "Apache",
  "summary": "Library for computing MD5 hashes of files with small memory usage.",
  "homepage": "http://www.joel.lopes-da-silva.com/2010/09/07/compute-md5-or-sha-hash-of-large-file-efficiently-on-ios-and-mac-os-x/",
  "authors": {
    "Joel Lopes Da Silva": "joel@lopes-da-silva.com"
  },
  "source": {
    "git": "https://github.com/JoeKun/FileMD5Hash.git",
    "commit": "6864c180c010ab4b0514ba5c025091e12ab01199"
  },
  "prefix_header_file": "Common/FileMD5Hash_Prefix.pch",
  "source_files": "Common/*.{h,c}",
  "requires_arc": false
}
```